# in php how to remove all special characters, uppercase letters, numbers and spaces

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is what i've got so far, but i cant seem to figure out the proper way to have it remove spaces. Any ideas?

```
preg_replace('[a-z]', "", strtolower($_GET["myvar"]));
```

Comment: also, for future reference, you can put a space in the character class: `[a-z ]` means "any character from a to z and spaces"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to remove everything except lowercase letters. If that is the case, try this:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', "", strtolower($_GET["myvar"]));
```

This is will transform `$_GET["myvar"]` to all lowercase letters then remove anything that isn't a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', strtolower($_GET['myvar']));
```

technically, there couldn't ever be any upper case letters, since you're guaranteeing that all letters will be lower case before the regex ever gets its hands on the string. In any case, this regex will remove anything that ISN'T a-z.

You almost had it, and were just missing the inversion (`^`) and the delimiters (`//`).