# remove whitespace and special character from string

Tags: php

i am using this code to save the uploaded file but the problem is it is allowing the file with name with special character and space.
for example it is allowing

```
hi how are you
```

but i dont want to allow any space ,special charater etc. here is my code .i tried with preg_replace in uri but after that i tried to upload file but nothing got uploaded.

```
function save_file($file) {
    $allowed_ext = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg');
    $ext = $file['name'];
    $ext = strtolower($ext);

    if (in_array($ext, $allowed_ext)) {
        die('Sorry, the file type is incorrect:'.$file['name']);
    }

    $fname = date("H_i",time()).'_'.get_rand(5);
    $dir = date("Ym",time());
    $folder = 'uploads/userfiles/'.$dir;
    $uri = $folder.'/'.$fname.'.'.$ext;

    if (!is_dir($folder))
        mkdir($folder, 0777);

    if (copy($file['tmp_name'],$uri))
        return $uri;
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Try to clearly indent your code and avoid using if statements without brackets. Make it easy on us and you get more code quality.

Comment: See also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032331/in-php-how-to-remove-all-special-characters-uppercase-letters-numbers-and-spac) and extend the expression to permit uppercase chars. `/[^a-z]/i`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To strip non letters out of a string you can use the following regular expression

```
$input = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $input);
```

Comment: can you please tell where in my code . i tried but it did not worked.please tell where in my code

Comment: @raju This single line is self explanatory. Make an effort.

Comment: i tried this but nothing got uploaded $uri = $folder.'/'.$fname.'.'.$ext;
$uri = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $uri);    there are several dependency on $uri so i have not changed the name in next line as php will execute from top to bottom

Comment: @raju It seems to me that you have lot more than this one question you asked above. For example, why is the input filename used as file-extension and why are the extensions from `$allowed_ext` not allowed? Have you ever run that piece of code you've posted in your question?

Comment: This will remove digits as well. Digits are not whitespace or special character.

Comment: For allowing the numbers you can update it with - $input = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $input);